# rich:tabPanel has a strange Behaviour: it does not select the correct tab

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, facelets

I've found a strange behaviour using rich:tabPanel in RichFaces 3.3.0.GA and Facelets 1.1.14

The problem occurs when I try to nest a tabPanel in a rich:panel, simpleTogglePanel, or h:panelGrid. The panel is in sever mode.

It suddenly switch to first tab. It's not that easy to reproduce:

If I've got three tabs:

- click on 1
- click on 2
- click on 3
- click on 2
- click on 3
- Sometimes (random) it goes to the first tab, instead of going to the third tab.

The tabs are not generated dynamically, but they are written in xml page.

I've got some custom tags in a taglib in another project (referenced via jar). This happens when I try to insert a rich:tabPanel between my custom tags using

In my tags there are no forms (a4j:form o h:form)

Any idea on how to solve this issue? I may start debugging richFaces, but it's a little hard to do, and I'm not even sure that the problem is in that (it may be in Facelets, for instance).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please elaboarate the problem more. I don't get the picture of "It suddenly switch to first tab." nor "it doesn't behave correctly". Edit your question to elaborate **both** the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are controlled by Javascript. Start with debugging JS. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) has an excellent JS debugger.

Good luck.